# Lower Intermediate level SQL Query: Using substring and OR

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web

Alright I will first admit that I am quite new to SQL.  I've probably made less than a dozen queries thus far and most of them were quite simple.  Now I have an intermediate level problem where I need to use the substring function and OR functionality of SQL, which I have never done.  Here is the problem/thinking pattern:

So on a webpage, I have 2 drop down lists, one which specifies Category and one which specifies County.  I need to take the Category and County from these drop down lists, and make an SQL query based off of them.

The SQL table I am looking at has column Counties, and column Category.  Counties is a text string which has all of the counties separated by comma.  Category is a text string as well, but is just a one word string.  So I need to query against this table and bring back any rows which share the same Category OR County as the drop down lists.

Here is my Pseudoquery I wrote down on paper which should at least describe my thinking here:

```
"SELECT * FROM ScholarshipsTable WHERE Category = '" + DDL1.Value() "' OR '" DDL2.Value() "' IS_SUBSTRING_OF Counties"
```

Can anyone tell me if I am on track here?  I don't think I am using Substring correctly at all.

Comment: Okay I'm studying answers, thank you all I will post results and accept an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the work for you

```
 SELECT * FROM ScholarshipsTable WHERE Category = '" + DDL1.Value() +"' OR  category like '%," + DDL2.Value()+ ",%'"
```

Note the way i have added **comma ,** in the above query to take csv into account

Comment: Thank you Ehsan I think you are on to something important with these commas here.

Comment: sry Ehsan been working on it this whole time and similar stuff, but yes it did

Answer (score 2):

The most consistent way to do "is substring of" is to use `like`"

```
SELECT *
FROM ScholarshipsTable
WHERE Category = '" + DDL1.Value() "' OR '" Counties like '%" + DDL2.Value() + "%'";
```

EDIT:

Buried in the question is the fact that the country drop down is a comma delimited list.  I think this answers the question:

```
SELECT *
FROM ScholarshipsTable
WHERE Category = '" + DDL1.Value() "' OR
      " concat(',', Counties, ',') like '%," + DDL2.Value() + ",%'";
```

The difference here are the commas in the `like` pattern and argument.  This prevents confusion between two counties where one name is contained in the other.

Note that I used the function `concat()` because no database is specified.  This might be `','+Counties+','` or ','||Counties||','.

Comment: this is not taking csv into consideration

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by the concat thing.  I'm going to try this without using it, I will select this as the answer as soon as I get it working.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the LIKE keyword:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ScholarshipsTable
WHERE Countries LIKE '%PHRASE 1%' OR
      Countries LIKE '%PHRASE 2%'
```

The % is the wildcard in the LIKE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating two tables? **Counties** (*fields: CountyID [primary key], CountyName*) and **Categories** (*fields: CategoryId [primary key], CategoryName*).

Then you could create a third table - **CountyCategories** with two fields: **CountyId** and **CategoryId** (*as primary key*).

CountyName and CategoryName should be indexed.

Your statement would go like this

```
SELECT *
FROM CategoryCounties CC
INNER JOIN Categories C on C.CategoryId = CC.CategoryId
INNER JOIN Counties CO on CO.CountyId = CC.CountyId
WHERE CC.CategoryId = 3
OR CO.CountyName = 'My County'  -- Are you sure you want to ORing instead of ANDing?
```